# Acessar váriavel de uma function em outra function

Tags: javascript, funções, promises

Estou começando no JavaScript e estou com a seguinte dificuldade: necessito pegar uma variável e acessa-la em outra função.

Já criei uma variável sem especificar nada tornando-a global, mas não deu certo por aqui, utilizando o `console` retorna como `undefined`.

Preciso pegar o que retorna de `axios.get()` seja o `.then` ou `.catch` e acessar ela em `btnElement.onclick = function ()`.

```javascript
var inputElement = document.querySelector('input');
var btnElement = document.querySelector('button');
var listElement = document.querySelector('.div lista');


btnElement.onclick = function () {
    var listItemElement = document.createElement('ul');

    pegarRepositorio();

    // QUERO USAR O "RESPONSE" AQUI

};


function pegarRepositorio() {

    var inputValue = inputElement.value;

    axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputValue}/repos`)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.warn('Erro 404 - Usuário não encontrado');
        });
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode fazer sua requisição de forma [assincrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas).
Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
Uma função assíncrona é diferente de uma função de síncrona, pois uma função assíncrona não bloqueia o processamento portanto função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução retornando o valor resolvido.

No caso eu testei com o valor id de usuário `mojombo` que foi o primeiro valor obtido na consulta https://api.github.com/users :

```js
let inputElement = document.querySelector('input');
let btnElement = document.querySelector('button');


btnElement.onclick = async function() {

  //Pausa a execucão até pegarRepositorio() retornar um valor ou falhar.
  let repositorio = await pegarRepositorio();
  //Verifica se houve erro
  if (repositorio.error == null) {
    //Caso não houver erros
    console.log(repositorio["data"]);
  } else {
    //Caso houver erros
    console.error(repositorio.error);
  }

};


async function pegarRepositorio() {
  let inputValue = inputElement.value;
  let d = {};
  try {
    //Pausa a execução até axios.get() retornar um valor ou falhar
    d = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputValue}/repos`, {
      timeout: 3000
    });
  } catch (err) {
    d.error = err;
  }
  return d;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="mojombo">
<button>Clique</button>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Boa tarde Augusto, show, deu certo por aqui. Apenas uma questão, preciso retornar na tela, caso o usuario seja digitado errado, deve ser retornado o erro 404... por isso o .then/.catch, como faço para manter eles?

Comment: @RafaelSimionato fiz uma edição na resposta e veja se atende suas expectativas.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode fazer Usando Return!
Fazendo assim a variável `response` terá o que o `axios.get()` retornar

```js
btnElement.onclick = function () {
    var listItemElement = document.createElement('ul');

    let response = pegarRepositorio();

};


function pegarRepositorio() {

    var inputValue = inputElement.value;

    return ( 
        axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${inputValue}/repos`)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.warn('Erro 404 - Usuário não encontrado');
        });
    )
};
```