# Como salvar os dados da api do github em um json

Tags: javascript, node.js

nao consigo entender pq nao esta dando certo, quero pegar esse conteudo em markdown e salvar em um arquivo json, mas sempre vem vazio, estou muito confuso

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
  Authorization: 'token xxx'
}

const url = `https://api.github.com/repos/tchapi/markdown-cheatsheet/contents`
const path = './testfile.json'

const dataList = (list) => {
  return list.map(async (item) => {
    const md = await fetch(item.download_url, headers).then((res) => res.text())
    return { name: item.name, content: md }
  })
}

const downloadFile = async (url, path) => {
  const result = await fetch(url, headers).then((res) => res.json())
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path)
  fileStream.write(JSON.stringify(await dataList(result)))
}

downloadFile(url, path)
```

o resultado no json aparece como:

```
[{},{}]
```

nao sei pq da esse problema, alguem tem alguma orientaçao?

Comment: Ha algum tempo respondi uma parecida, veja se de alguma forma o ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/446833/137387

Comment: Infelizmente eu tento mas nao consigo resolver, apareceu no log do terminal assim:
[
  Promise { <pending> },
]

Answer (score 0):

O problema acontece quando você passa pelo `dataList()` pois ele busca o arquivo license e README.md e eles não são json igual você está pensando.

se você alterar a linha `fileStream.write(JSON.stringify(await dataList(result)))`  para `fileStream.write(JSON.stringify(result))` já salvaria o JSON conforme você imagina.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: mas eu preciso chamar a funçao dataList() com o result justamente para me trazer o conteudo em markdown que preciso, eu testei em um repositorio só com markdown e mesmo assim nao funcionou por causa das promises, nao entendi pq. Nao entendi sua reposta "eles nao sao json igual voce esta pensando", mas usando o JSON.stringify pra salvar ja nao bastaria?